# rubber band effect in android - with Motion

Tags: android

I'm creating **Rubber Band** effect in my `ListView`.

So for that, I created the class which extends `AdapterView<Adapter>`. When user ups the mouse I am setting the co-ordinate again so it is again re-positioning and there is similar effect but the problem is there is no motion effect. So can someone tell me how can I provide a motion effect?